# Implementing a Generic method

Tags: c#, .net, generics, c#-4.0, interface

I created an interface  with one method, the ability to copy the contents of one object into another object of the same type (the actual functionality is irrelevant to the question).

```
public interface IDeepClonable
{
    void DeepClone<T>(T other);
}
```

I'm having trouble with a proper implementation.

What I really would like is to implement it like this (where this is inside ClassA, which implements IDeepClonable)

```
public void DeepClone<ClassA>(ClassA other)
{
    this.A = other.A;
}
```

However this does not work, as the 'other' object is not recognized as an instance of ClassA by the compiler (why?)

This does not work either, as it gives a 'the constraints for type parameter T must match the (...) interface method.

```
public void DeepClone<T>(T other) where T : ClassA
{
    this.A= other.A;
}
```

I can solve all problems by changing the interface to take in an object instead of a generic constraint, but I was hoping for a more elegant solution.

I can also solve this by turning the interface into a generic interface, but then then that forces me to cast to that generic interface.

Comment: BTW, `DeepClone` is the wrong name; a method named `DeepClone` ought to return a copy.  You should name that `DeepCloneFrom` or something like that.

Comment: I would suggest that if you're going to be doing much deep cloning, it might be good to define the `IImmutableClonable<T>` with method `T AsImmutable()`, `IModifiableClone<U>` with method `U AsNewMutable()`, and `IFullClone<T,U>` inheriting both of the above.  Immutable objects would simply return themselves from their `AsImmutable()` implementations; `AsNewMutable()` would return something that allows, at minimum, whatever methods of mutation are required by `U`'s contract.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're trying to use the [CRTP](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/02/03/curiouser-and-curiouser.aspx).

You need to write

```
public interface IDeepClonable<out T> where T : IDeepClonable<T>
{
    void DeepClone(T other);
}

public class ClassA : IDeepClonable<ClassA> {
    void DeepClone(ClassA other) { ... }
}
```

However, this means that any code that uses `IDeepClonable` must itself become generic, which will end up becoming unwieldy.

The CLR type system is not rich enough to do what you really want.

Comment: One problem with using the CRTP here is that one might have a base class which includes both cloneable and non-cloneable derivatives, and non-cloneable derivatives might have cloneable sub-derivatives.  Does adding the constraint to `T` allow one to do anything one can't do in its absence?  Also, is there any reason not to make `T` a covariant (`out`) type parameter?

Comment: That's supposed to be contravariant (`in`), not covariant.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have declared a generic method in the interface, and you have to implement exactly like that in the derived class:

```
public class ClassA : IDeepClonable 
{ 
    void DeepClone<T>(T other) { /* some implementation here */ } 
}
```

Something different than that won't work.

Said that, why you need this kind of complexity, you don't need the generic here, just implement as:

```
public interface IDeepClonable 
{ 
    void DeepClone(IDeepClonable other); 
} 

public class ClassA : IDeepClonable 
{ 
    void DeepClone(IDeepClonable other)
    {
         // just to be sure ....
         if (other is ClassA) 
         {
             var o = (ClassA)other;
             this.A = o.A; 
         }
    } 
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I was hoping to avoid this sort of implementation though.